# Are zero-copy services possible (nodelet + rosservice)?

Tags: ros, shared-ptr, service, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With nodelets you can have zero-copy message passing via shared pointers. Is there a mechanism to do the same with services? Will data be copied running ros::ServiceClient::call() if both service client and service server are nodelets on the same manager?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12685/are-zero-copy-services-possible-(nodelet-+-rosservice)?/) by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1924 on 2012-01-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe this has been implemented.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Matias](https://answers.ros.org/users/11721/matias/) on 2014-10-21**:
Where should this feature be requested? I believe this is important and would like to know if there's any challenge in implementing this.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-10-21**:
You can request it on ros_comm on github. But it will probably be an untargeted enhancement, if you want it soon a pull-request will probably be necessary.

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2015-10-02**:
did anything change in that regard in the last few years?